# AngularJS app packaging for autonomous application

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, package

I wrote an angularJS app (with nodeJS and ExpressJS as my server). My app is totally independent from the server (I used pouchDB for the data). I would like to create an app/package that can be run from a computer or tablet. How can I do that?

I'm sure there are already lot of questions/answers about this topic but I couldn't find the right solution so I apologize in advance!

Thanks

Comment: So you want to have an app for android and so on, that can be run as webapp with the same code?

Comment: yes! PC/tablets etc... in fact I just want to make my app working in offline mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you r looking for an **full-stack** framework, i can really recommend [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/).

It is a framework, that contains it's own customizable ui-framework(build on sass bootstrap), it is build on cordova aka phonegap and makes it easy to deploy and test the code on android, ios, ... . It is also optimized for angularjs and offers for most functions a directive.

I really love it. I did write a blogpost in german: [kkonstantin/ionic](http://kkonstantin.de/ionic-hybride-apps-leicht-gemacht/)

Maybe take your **existing frontend javascript code and make use of a css framework**, to make it look great for all window sizes. 
Like: [Ratchet (build on bootstrap)](http://goratchet.com/)

Then you just make use of [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) to deploy your html/css/javascript code to the plattforms.

Comment: Thanks Konstantin but I'm a bit lost... I'm new to node.js and I have some lacks! I looked at your mentioned solutions and I see only mobile apps and not windows PC... I also don't understand how these solutions work? How does it simulate the expressJS part (my current server side)?

Comment: your backend code will still run on your server. 
The frameworks just take the client side implementation and deploy em as apps. The code, which is deployed is a plain webapplication. You can provide the same code as a basic website and apps for windows phone, ios, android.

Comment: Ok, make sense...but my server (ExpressJS) plays a crucial role to make my app 'readable' (such as the view engine and routes). Do these solutions create such environment? If not, how an offline app can render without connecting to NodeJS? One more thing, do you have such solution for desktop app?

Comment: Yeah that all requires, that everything is clientside rendered, like with AngularJS. For offline capability check html5 cache manifest http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp3. 

With "desktop app" your mean a native program like starting a .exe ?